# vue js как изменить значения в array

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

html

```
<div id="todo-list-example">
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="addNewTodo">

    <input
      v-model="newTodoText"
      id="new-todo"
    >
    <button>+</button>
  </form>
  <ul>
    <li
      is="todo-item"
      v-for="(todo, index) in todos"
      v-bind:key="todo.id"
      v-bind:title="todo.title"
      v-on:remove="todos.splice(index, 1)"
    ></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js

```
  Vue.component('todo-item', {
  template: '\
    <li>\
      {{ title }}\
      <button v-on:click="$emit(\'remove\')">-</button>\
    </li>\
  ',
  props: ['title']
})

var z = new Vue({
  el: '#todo-list-example',
  data: {
    newTodoText: '',
    todos: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: '4500'
      }
    ],
    nextTodoId: 2
  },
  methods: {
    addNewTodo: function () {
      this.todos.push({
        id: this.nextTodoId++,
        title: this.newTodoText
      })
      this.newTodoText = ''
    }
  }
})
```

вопрос такой: есть в приложении инпут и список, в который добавляются значения с инпута, как сделать так чтоб можно было пересчитовать значения? Например я ввожу 4500 - выводит 4500, далее вожжу 4525 выводит - 4525 (+25) , и тд.

**приложение:** https://jsfiddle.net/xju73L81/

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете добавить [computed](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) свойство, которое всегда будет возвращать сумму массива, и использовать его как обычную переменную.

Comment: Пора уже в документации Vue вынести доки по computed (и в каких случаях его применять) на главную...